# Fade in on automated scrolldown (a href="#")

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have image button:

```
                <a href="#our-apps"><img src="assets/img/arrow-down.png" width="350"/></a>
```

It will use jquery to smooth scrolldown to div with id #our-apps.

I want to fade in div containter with id #our-apps when someone is scrolling or when click on image that will use smooth scrolling method to auto scroll down to #our-apps.

Here is code of div #our-apps:

```
            <div class="main" id="our-apps">
            <section>
                <h1>Our Apps</h1>
                <img src="assets/img/htc.png" align="centerleft" alt="HTC" />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <img src="assets/img/htc.png" align="centerright" alt="HTC" />
            </section>
        </div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: zasto toliko "$nbsp"??

Comment: testirao sam nesto pa sam stavio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of achieving that is to watch window scroll and check if your div is within visible area

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() > $('#our-apps').offset().top){
    $('#our-apps').addClass('visible');
  }
});
```

scss

```
#our-apps{
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  &.visible{
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Why I used opacity instead of jquery's hide/show is because i need to het div offset - and if it has "display: none" property, offset equals 0.

See it here: https://jsfiddle.net/auzxqx42/

Comment: Have you tried my jsfiddle example ? For me it works on every browser.
If you copied it to your app - you sure you compiled scss to css ?

Comment: Ouhh.I didnt compile it to css. Now, when I compiled it, my div is hidden and doesnt even display.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var op = $("#our-apps").outerHeight();
var f = false;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
f = true;
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= (($(document).height() - $(this).height()) - $('#our-apps').innerHeight())) {
    
    $('#our-apps').fadeIn('slow');
  }else{
    f = false;
    $('#our-apps').fadeOut('slow');
  }
})
```

```css
#our-apps {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#our-apps">
  <img src="assets/img/arrow-down.png" width="350" />
</a>


<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<div class="main" id="our-apps">
  <section>
    <h1>Our Apps</h1>
    <img src="assets/img/htc.png" align="centerleft" alt="HTC" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <img src="assets/img/htc.png" align="centerright" alt="HTC" />
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: It's working when scrolling manually but when I click on my image button to use smooth scrolldown to #our-apps its not working (it cant go to #our-apps, it just stay there and doesnt do anything).